# 404 error when accessing a shared drive via Google Drive API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api

I'm trying to list the metadata of a shared drive. Below is the code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

SCOPES = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'
]
creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=8080)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

The code above works; it can authenticate successfully.

```
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
file_id = '0AFmX-a2BvgHBUk9PVA'
results = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

The output of the code is the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in
>
> results = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py",
> line 134, in positional_wrapper
> return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py",
> line 935, in execute
> raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting
> https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0AFmX-a2BvgHBUk9PVA/permissions?alt=json
> returned "File not found: 0AFmX-a2BvgHBUk9PVA.". Details: "[{'domain':
> 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'File not found:
> 0AFmX-a2BvgHBUk9PVA.', 'locationType': 'parameter', 'location':
> 'fileId'}]">

The file definitely exists. Is the code wrong? Am I using the right permission scope? Do I need to use a service account instead of an OAuth client ID?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to retrieve the permission list from the shared Drive.
- You can access to the shared Drive.

In this case, please include `supportsAllDrives` to the query parameter for the request as follows.

> `supportsAllDrives`: Whether the requesting application supports both My Drives and shared drives. (Default: false)

#### From:

```
results = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

#### To:

```
results = service.permissions().list(fileId=file_id, supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/list)

Comment: @ITGarry Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.